# User clicks Facebook like button, than shares content, but it's not showing on users own wall

Tags: facebook

When a user clicks the "like" button on a piece of content of our site, they get the share box as well (normal). They decide to write a comment and share it to their wall. Everything seems to be fine however, when going to the users own wall the share doesn't display. If the user goes to their activity log, the "like" is there but nothing more.

The users may get "likes" on their share from their friends so people are seeing the share but what would cause the user to not be able to see it on their own wall?

We haven't changed anything in terms of the FB meta tags, etc. This is sort of random behavior.

Has anyone else experienced this? Sorry I did search for previous questions and couldn't find any with an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if those are supposed to show up as two different items in activity log – I think it still “is” just a like, only one with a message attached.

Comment: Has the URL for which the like button is configured been [scraped](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) by Facebook?